# iPhone 6/6+ camera | size of taken photos?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

What is the size (in pixels) of a photo taken by iPhone 6/6+ cameras? Or where can I find any info about this? I need to setup GPUImageCameraView's frame size.

Comment: Hey, if you are about to downvote, you are about to explain the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the physical pixels on the screen, the iPhone 6+ is 1080 x 1920, while the iPhone 6 is 750 x 1334.

If you are referring to screen size, the iPhone 6+ is 414 x 736 points, while the iPhone 6 is 375 x 667 points.

Hope this helps!